# Putty: Access Denied phpmyadmin using aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, putty, rds

Hello I am trying to connect my RDS instance to my phpmyadmin but every time i move it from "localhost" to the "ec2...." it takes a second and gives me these messages

```
Error
MySQL said: Documentation

#2002 - Connection timed out
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

and i tried looking it up but I find stuff that has to deal with more php code than putty with aws ec2 instance. So what i basically want to do is connect my aws RDS instance to my phpmyadmin so I can start using it.

I am running the command on my local computer using PUTTY. I installed apache and MySQL properly on the PUTTY and got to phpmyadmin but when i switch to rds sever i get the error messages. When I connect i use these commands.

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '__FILL_IN_DETAILS__';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = '__FILL_IN_DETAILS__';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '__FILL_IN_DETAILS__';
```

And I use this security group for my RDS instance that was created by RDS with a 
type of "MYSQL/Aurora"
Protocol of TCP
Port Range 3306
Source as "Custom"
But for my EC2 I use a different security group which takes "all traffic".

Comment: Can you ping the RDS machine?

Comment: not sure how to do that

Comment: Could you please Edit your question to provide more details? For example: Where are you running the command (eg on a local computer or on an EC2 instance)? What is the configuration that works (eg is MySQL installed on the same computer)? What do you change when it doesn't work (eg do you point to the RDS instance)? What command are you using to connect? What is the Security Group associated with the RDS instance? The more you can tell us, the more likely we'll be able to assist.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, i edited my question

Comment: You said you're running a command on your computer using PUTTY, which command is that? Are the actual values `__FILL_IN_DETAILS__` actually in your configuration file? Those need to be changed in order to connect properly, and is probably be why the host isn't responding: you need to provide the actual hostname there. You probably should use auth_type cookie instead of config for security, but that's not the cause of the error you're seeing.

Comment: Yea thats the code there but i didn't want to put out that information just in case but i gave it so you guys can have an idea on what it looks like.